# Kivy on_file_drop event doesn't work anymore

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building a python app with Kivy. Where a main Window opens and the user can drop a file. This file is then processed.

This code has worked in the past. But after touching it an setting up a new pyenv variant with likely a new Kivy version. The drop event is not working anymore. The window opens but the users file drop has no effect anymore.

```py
class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    path = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drop2 = str('Drop the YNAB4 Budget CSV here!')
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)
        
    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        
        df = kw.createDF(file_path.decode('utf-8'))
        
        if not isinstance(df, str):
            df = kw.shapeDF(df)
            df = kw.toDateTime(df)
            if not isinstance(df, str):
                df = kw.rmvCurrncySymbols(df)
                df = kw.toNum(df)
                df = kw.sumQuart(df)
        #for each page one call
            
                pp = PdfPages(asupport + '/Kwarterli/' + date.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y') + '_kwarterli.pdf')
                kw.multiple_plot(1, df, pp)
                kw.multiple_plot(2, df, pp)
                kw.multiple_plot(3, df, pp)
                kw.multiple_plot(4, df, pp)
                pp.close()        
                # Update the label
                Clock.schedule_once(self.setSucess, 0.5)
                path = (asupport + '/Kwarterli/' + date.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y') + '_kwarterli.pdf')
                subprocess.call(['open', path])
                
                self.function_interval = Clock.schedule_interval(self.backtolive, 20)
            else:    
                Clock.schedule_once(self.setFail, 0.5)
                self.function_interval = Clock.schedule_interval(self.backtolive, 20)          
        else:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.setFail, 0.5)
            self.function_interval = Clock.schedule_interval(self.backtolive, 20)
        return  
    
    def setSucess(self, *args):  
        self.ids.drop2.text = str('Success! You can find the Kwarterli here: \n') + desktop + '/Kwarterli/' + date.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y') + '_kwarterli.pdf'
        self.ids.BL.background_color = (0.8,.8,.8,.8)
        
    def setFail(self, *args):  
        self.ids.drop2.text = str('Fail! Something is wrong with that file: \n') 
        self.ids.BL.background_color = (0.8,.8,.8,.8)
    
    def backtolive(self, *args):
        self.ids.BL.background_color = (0.5,.5,.5,.5)
        self.ids.drop2.text = str('Drop the YNAB4 Budget CSV here!')
        
    
    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()
            

        

        self.dismiss_popup()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by re-installing Kiwi